# How to make a button settle at the right bottom corner in all devices?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to make the button settled at the bottom right corner but for mobile devices it is moving to the top

```
<div class="form-group" style ="margin-top: 12%; float:right; position: relative; ">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="btndisclaimer">accept</button>

            </div>
```

Comment: you want to fix the `button` to the bottom right corner of the screen always, even when user scrolls down?

Comment: @RohitKumar  i have a footer and top of the footer at right corner the button should appear

Comment: for the button positioning to the right use `float: right` and to shift the button to top of the footer, use `margin-top: -75px`

Comment: do you want the button to be visible always, to be it in the viewport always? even when the footer is very bottom to the page and is not visible, the button should always be visible if the user is viewing the header... for this you have to use `position: fixed` to make the button fixed in the viewport always..

Comment: its working thanks for ur help

Comment: thanks to whom?? me or the answer you have selected??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `CSS`.

```css
#btndisclaimer {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 12%; float:right; position: relative; ">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="btndisclaimer">accept</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a footer and top of the footer right corner the button should come it should come

Comment: What's the height of footer?

Comment: height:75px footer height

Comment: Do you want the button to be always visible on the page?

Comment: yes and the button is going to top for mobile devices when i give bottom 75px

Comment: You are contradicting 2 of your comments. Do you want the button in the extreme bottom-right corner or you want it just above the footer?

Comment: @AndroidBeginer See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/1gupfvnw/4/).

Answer (score 2):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/1gupfvnw/)

You have to change your `position:relative` to `position:absolute`

Now, to make it appear in the bottom-right, use the style given below:

```
bottom:0; 
right:0;
```

So the complete **HTML** would be like

```
<div class="form-group" style="float:right; position: absolute;bottom:0; right:0;">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="btndisclaimer">accept</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want the button to be placed always at the bottom-right corner, use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`.

Comment: i have one more div tag on the top of the button and the button should be below the that div tag

Comment: the second one is which i rquire but for mobile devices it is going top

Comment: no, the second one wont go to the top..see resizing the fiddle..it wont go up..it will always stay at the bottom..

Comment: @Lal What about [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/1gupfvnw/3/). The button is moving up with the scrolling.

Comment: great..:) glad that it helped..:)

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla that was what i mentioned in my answer, if he wants the button to be always at the bottom, use fixed positioning instead..